# Trying to fill Array list with fori (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android

I've got an ArrayList consisting of items that have such fields:

```
    ImageView recipePic;
    TextView recipeName;
    TextView recipeIngridients;
    TextView recipeLong;
```

And I add items to the ArrayList like this:

```
recyclerViewItems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.porridge1,
                    getString(R.string.recipe_name_1), getString(R.string.recipe_short_1),
                    getString(R.string.recipe_ingridients_1),
                    getString(R.string.recipe_long_1)));
recyclerViewItems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.porridge2,
                    getString(R.string.recipe_name_2),getString(R.string.recipe_short_2),
                    getString(R.string.recipe_ingridients_2),
                    getString(R.string.recipe_long_2)));
```

etc.

I wanted to make code shorter and pretier and produced such code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        recyclerViewItems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(Integer.parseInt("R.drawable.porridge"+i),
                getString(Integer.parseInt("R.string.recipe_name_"+i)),
                getString(Integer.parseInt("R.string.recipe_short_"+i)),
                getString(Integer.parseInt("R.string.recipe_ingridients_"+i)),
                getString( Integer.parseInt("R.string.recipe_long_"+i))));        }
```

As all the resources follow the same naming scheme I thought that such code would be better but it doesn't work. I think it's because you can't parse integer from "R.drawable.porridge1" even though "R.drawable.porridge1" counts as integer. Am I understanding this right? Although concatenating only works on strings... Are there similiar ways of upgrading first solution?

Comment: The expression ``Integer.parseInt("R.string.recipe_name_"+i)`` will not work because it tries to convert your string to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store items as arrays in XML resources

for strings like name, Ingredients, Long you will use string-array
for example

```
<string-array name="numbers">
    <item>@string/one</item>
    <item>@string/two</item>
    <item>@string/three</item>
</string-array>
```

and for drawables use integer-array for example

```
<integer-array name="drawables">
    <item>@drawable/one</item>
    <item>@drawable/two</item>
    <item>@drawable/three</item>
</integer-array>
```

and use TypedArray to read every image id for example

```
TypedArray array = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawables);
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(array.getResourceId(index, defaultValue));
```

and now you can use for loop to fill your ArrayList

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    recyclerViewItems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(
            array.getResourceId(i,-1),
            recipeName[i],
            recipeShort[i],
            recipeIngridients[i],
            recipeLong[i]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed a few bits and pieces and now code actually works as I wanted it to do. It's kinda cumbersome, but it'll look better with bigger number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AmrDeveloper I understood how all this should work.

First you add all the strings to arrays in arrays.xml like

```
<array name="recipeLongs">
        <item>@string/recipe_long_1</item>
        <item>@string/recipe_long_2</item>
        <item>@string/recipe_long_3</item>
    </array>
    <array name="recipePics">
        <item>@drawable/porridge1</item>
        <item>@drawable/porridge2</item>
        <item>@drawable/porridge3</item>
    </array>
```

No need to make special types of arrays.

Then I've added following code to MainActivity:

```
TypedArray picsArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.recipePics);
        TypedArray recipeNamesArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.recipeNames);
        TypedArray recipeShortsArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.recipeShorts);
        TypedArray recipeIngridientsArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.recipeIngridients);
        TypedArray recipeLongsArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.recipeLongs);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            recyclerViewItems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(
                    picsArray.getResourceId(i,-1),
                    getString(recipeNamesArray.getResourceId(i,-1)),
                    getString(recipeShortsArray.getResourceId(i,-1)),
                    getString(recipeIngridientsArray.getResourceId(i,-1)),
                    getString(recipeLongsArray.getResourceId(i,-1))));
         }
```